# Get all select Values in Java

Tags: java, jsp, select, struts2

I have a SELECT tag in JSP page that contains few values :

```
<select name="selectNumber" size="3" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
    <option value="11">eleven</option>
    <option value="12">twelve</option>
    <option value="13">thirette</option>
    <option value="14">fourteen</option>
    <option value="15">fifteen</option>
    <option value="16">sixteen</option>
    <option value="17">seventeen</option>
    <option value="18">eighteen</option>
    <option value="19">nineteen</option>
    <option value="20">twenty</option>
  </select>
```

And I want to get all that values in a Java Class.

What I have tried that :

`HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)ServletActionContext.getRequest();
String[] selectedNumbers = req.getParameterValues("selectNumber");`

But that Array only contains the value I am selecting, and If I don't select any value it contains null. But I want all the option values of the select Tag in java class. Any help?

I am using Struts 2 framework.

Comment: Makes zero sense. You know all values from the select before user have submitted the form, no need to send them to the action.

Comment: I am populating option values in a select tag as user needs, it is dynamic, So the question arose :) @AleksandrM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to send all the Options to Your Servlet then you must first select them all using simply using Jquery

## Before Submitting the Form

```
$("#selectNumber option").prop('selected',true);
```

Note `#`is used for Id , which i prefer if you need to use only name then try

```
$('[name="selectNumber"]');
```